# Is it safe to remove ASCII non-printable characters from UTF-8 string?

Tags: utf-8, ascii

I'm parsing strings from users input (UTF-8) as ASCII and removing all characters based on this PCRE expression: `/[\x00-\x1F\x7F]/`. I wonder if this can lead to some kind of corruption in any UTF-8 character?

Thanks!

Comment: Well, in many programming environments, reading bytes as ASCII that don't correspond to ASCII code units will either throw an exception or replace with '?'. Why don't you read it as UTF-8 and then remove the Unicode characters you don't want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you are killing all the codepoints equal to the values you specified (0 to 31 and 127); there's no risk of corrupting anything else, as UTF-8 multibyte sequences are all made of bytes with the high bit set (>=128).